# Is calling require('mymodule') correct after initializing 'mymodule' somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Let's assume i have a module that connects to the database by using some configuration. I don't want to pass around the configuration or the loaded module, i just want to initialize the database.js module in my main module (here app.js) and then be able to use it elsewhere in my code without initializing or passing the configuration.

My question is, is this approach correct with regards to what's been said here in this [link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats)

Here is the example.

// database.js

```
const mongodb

let config = null;

exports.init = (conf) {
    config = conf;
}

exports.getConnection = () {
    const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    return new MongoClient(config.mongodb.url);
}
```

// app.js

```
const { init } = require('./database.js');

// load config ...

init(config);
```

// some module in the lib folder

```
const { getConnection } = require('../../database.js');

// do something with getConnection
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200652/please-explain-object-versioning-in-the-nodejs-module-system/201212#201212

Comment: you can use ```require_once()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is correct. JS modules are evaluated only once under normal circumstances, this can be used in situations like this once.

Notice that the configuration needs to be initialized before `database` module will be used in other modules:

```
const { init } = require('./database.js');

init(config);

require('some-module-that-uses-database');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine. Both NodeJS's `require` and ES6's `import` are defined in their very specs to only load a given module once. Any `require` / `import` statement after that which tries to import the same code will simply return a reference to a "cached" version of what was loaded the first time, meaning all modules which load it will reference the same object and can access any changes made to it by other modules.